# Failed isochronous start. Error: 0x2 ;When starting reading from 2 cameras PTGrey

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have a PTGrey FL3-U3-13E4C-C USB 3 camera. I am able to read and store images for a single camera from the default code provided by PTGrey.
But when I try to run the MultipleCameraEx for testing with 2 Cameras connected, I get the Failed isochronous start Error.
I tried manually setting the number of cameras to 2 and running the code without the for loop, I still get the same error for 2 Cameras.
I get the following error.

FlyCapture2 library version: 2.10.3.266
Application build date: Apr  8 2017 17:45:42

Number of cameras detected: 2

*** CAMERA INFORMATION ***
Serial number - 16362359
Camera model - Flea3 FL3-U3-13E4C
Camera vendor - Point Grey Research
Sensor - E2v EV76C560 (1/1.8" Color CMOS)
Resolution - 1280x1024
Firmware version - 2.15.3.3
Firmware build time - Wed Jul 29 16:41:55 2015

*** CAMERA INFORMATION ***
Serial number - 16362353
Camera model - Flea3 FL3-U3-13E4C
Camera vendor - Point Grey Research
Sensor - E2v EV76C560 (1/1.8" Color CMOS)
Resolution - 1280x1024
Firmware version - 2.15.3.3
Firmware build time - Wed Jul 29 16:41:55 2015

Error Trace:
Source: IidcCameraInternal.cpp(469) Built: Oct 20 2016 20:17:21 - Error starting isochronous stream.
+-> From: Iso.cpp(2046) Built: Oct 20 2016 20:16:34 - Failed isochronous start. Error: 0x2.

Comment: Did you find out what was happening @ashwath-narayan ?
I'm experiencing the same error with just one camera and simply running FlyCapture2Test...

Answer (score 5):

If your developing under Linux, your issue might be connected to the maximum available amount of memory allocated to the USB subsystem, being too small *(that was the cause of my issue!)*.

To use multiple cameras the usbcore variable `usbfs_memory_mb` should be set suitably large *(e.g. 1024)*. In my case, even with just one single Point Grey Blackfly BFLY-U3-23S6C camera, the default buffer allocated *(16 on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)* was too small.

To do that use

```
$ sudo modprobe usbcore usbfs_memory_mb=1024
```

**OR**

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1024 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb'
```

**The change will be valid until the next restart.**

**To make the change permanent** add `options usbcore usbfs_memory_mb=1024` to an appropriate `/etc/modprobe.d` file *(e.g. `/etc/modprobe.d/usbcore.conf`)*.

**To check what is the current setting** of `usbfs_memory_mb` use

```
$ sudo cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb
```

Comment: For me the second solution worked (not the first)

`$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1024 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb'`